# What is the shape of an image tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I recently started learning Tensorflow, in particular I want to use Convolutional Neural Networks for image classification. I have been looking at the android demo in the official repository, in particular this example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowImageClassifier.java

On line 145, it creates a tensor with the input data of the image, as such:

```
inferenceInterface.feed(inputName, floatValues, 1, inputSize, inputSize, 3);
```

Now, I have been trying to understand what this is doing, and it ends up calling this method: [Tensor.create](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/Tensor.html#create(long[],%20java.nio.FloatBuffer)). The thing I don't understand is why the shape of this tensor, given by the input parameters to this function (also called "dimensions"), is `{1, inputSize, inputSize, 3}`. the second and third dimensions are the image width and height, and the fourth dimension is the RGB data of the image. But why does it have the first dimension as 1? Shouldn't the shape of this Tensor be `{inputSize, inputSize, 3}` instead? I guess since the dimension is 1 it makes no difference, but I suppose there has to be a reason for this notation and I don't understand it.

Comment: is the standard in pytorch `[B, C, H , W]` or some other (arbitrary order)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tensorflow works with batches of images.
The model, thus, accepts a batch of images each with shape `inputSize x inputSize x 3`.

The `1` is the batch size. Thus, in practice, you're feeding the network a batch with a single image that's a tensor with shape `1 x inputSize x inputSize x 3`

Comment: This is then something particular to tensorflow, right? The neural network still has an input of `inputsize x inputsize x 3`, so if the first dimension were anything other than 1, the neural network would be executed more than once, and we would get multiple predictions?

Comment: Yes this is particular to tensorflow. The model has been trained using batches of images, therefore the network has been defined to accepect batch of images and execute the predictions in parallel. The network input is, in reality `[None, inputSize, inputSize, 3]`. Where `None` means every value from 1 to infinity.
Thus, you can feed as input a single (batch with size 1) or multiple images (batch with size >1) and get a batch of prediction, one for every input image

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll look more into that to learn tensorflow particularities :D.

Comment: is the standard in pytorch `[B, C, H , W]` or some other (arbitrary order)?

Comment: @CharlieParker I haven't understood your question. If you're asking if pytorch uses [B,C,H,W], then yes, that's true. TensorFlow uses [B, H, W, C] instead